# IIS stopped logging

Tags: iis, logging, iis-7.5

IIS 7.5 has stopped logging all traffic for a single site (of a couple of dozen on the same box), and I can't work out why. It stopped logging at exactly midday on Friday last week, and nothing since. All log files for other sites are as expected. So far I've checked;

- Logging configuration is the same as other sites (W3C logging to a directory, one file per day)
- NTFS ACLs on the log folder are OK (inherited from the parent, the same as other log folders)
- disabled and re-enabled logging
- stopped and re-started the site

I've not restarted IIS or the server, but it was rebooted last night (Sunday) for Windows Updates, ie this problem pre-dates those updates and reboot.

Is there any way I can debug the logging process itself? All attempts to search for debug and logging just get me stuff about debugging requests, not the logging engine itself.

Comment: Just a stupid question: did someone change the DNS record for the hostname of that site which now points to a different server, so there is nothing to log? I suppose the last log file (Friday) contains only requests until a certain hour (when DNS change took effect everywhere).

Comment: IIS only logs when there's activity, so are you sure that the web site is getting hit?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but the site was still active, verified by a change to content being served as expected.

Comment: FWIW, it just happened to me as well, exactly at 12:00:48 - investigating..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, I removed and recreated the log directory, and things started logging again, so I assume there was some kind of ACL problem, although it wasn't obvious.