# IIS on Windows 2019 stops logging web requests in September

Tags: logging, windows-server-2019, iis-10

scary problem with IIS on Windows 2019 Standard, IIS is not writing W3C log files! I did see this [similar item](https://serverfault.com/questions/340083/iis-stopped-logging), but did not need to make new directories

- Three Windows Standard 2019 servers running under ESXi 6.7.
- Patches applied from August 2020, OS Build 17763.1397
- They use a shared configuration, distributed with DFS

Logging configured globally to use

- 1 log file per Site
- format W3C (with a custom field CF-Connecting-IP)
- Encoding UTF-8
- Destination: log file only
- Rollover: weekly

Configured on each web site (over 2000 sites), we place the log file in a directory like `d:\www-logs\hostname.domain.com`

Running smoothly in production since February 2020

At midnight UTC on August 31, all three servers quit logging W3C files in the specified log directories!
Notice the gap in 1 representative log file directory

```
7/18/2020   4:58PM  u_ex200703_x.log
7/25/2020   4:59PM  u_ex200704_x.log
7/31/2020   4:59PM  u_ex200705_x.log
8/1/2020    2:04PM  u_ex20080_x.log
8/8/2020    4:59PM  u_ex200802_x.log
8/15/2020   4:59PM  u_ex200803_x.log
8/22/2020   4:59PM  u_ex200804_x.log
8/29/2020   4:59PM  u_ex200805_x.log
8/31/2020   4:21PM  u_ex200806_x.log
9/4/2020    4:59PM  u_ex200904_x.log
9/4/2020    5:11PM  u_ex200905_x
```

(servers are in Pacific time, -7:00 UTC)

Colleague discovered this on Sept 3...
I rebooted the server, no change. It still serves pages normally, without logging activity.
When I watch the server with PROCMON, no attempt is made to write to files in the log directories, even as web sites remain responsive.
I verified global Logging is enabled, and that logging per site is also enabled.
The W3C Logging Service is running.

I changed Logging at the global IIS level to Daily... servers began to log hits immediately, in a new file.
Today, I observe that log files roll over OK at midnight UTC.

August might have been a bit unusual, in that weekly files reached a sixth file... could Microsoft fail to handle cases of more than 5 weeks in a month?

I am sure there is no way to recover the lost log records. Any experiences to the contrary?
Has anyone else observed this at log roll over?